# GNU compilers on xcode(mac)

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, xcode7, gnu

I have installed gnu compilers on my mac. GCC version-6.1.0
I also have Xcode 7.3.1.
However, I am having difficulty in using them with xcode. How can I use the gnu standard gnu library with xcode?

P.S.
When typing the following command in the terminal window `xcode-select --install`, I get the following error:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

But, I don't find any prompt to install the updates.
Please help
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to use GNU compilers with Xcode? Or how to install command-line tools? Or how to update command-line tools? Also, you don't say *how* you installed the GNU compiler - from source, or using `hombrew`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am asking how I can use gnu compilers with xcode?(I installed them form source, not with Homebrew)